# Order of military ranks

Tags: military

What is the order of rank in all branches of the Military?
Is a captain higher than a private? Do different branches have unique titles? And which branch would be in charge of space travel? Navy, air force or army?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:United_States_uniformed_services_comparative_ranks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative_army_officer_ranks_of_Europe

Comment: Those two links where a quick Google search. Please do not ask questions easily answered by Google.

Comment: As far as which branch would be in charge, that's a matter of opinion (of the executive or legislature of the country whose space forces you're considering). A common trope in SF is to consider the space forces as a navy-like service, but there's no reason that this will necessarily be so in the real world.

Comment: This question is not about worldbuilding, so I voted to close as 'off-topic.'

Comment: @RayO'Kalahjan I disagree with that, we're looking to create a comprehensive database of questions and answers here, so even if it's easily found on google, if it's not here it's a valid question. As long as it's on topic that is, which this is definitely not.

Comment: @bendl To quote from the downvote mouseover text, "This question does not show any research effort;..." This is why the question was poorly received.

Comment: @sphennings I agree completely that this should be closed, but I don't think closing because it's easily googleable is a good idea

Comment: @bendl As you can see above "The users who voted to close this question gave this specific reason: "This question does not appear to be about worldbuilding, within the scope defined in the help center."" This reason was selected by every one of the five users (myself included) who voted that this question should be closed. Downvotes and close votes are separate mechanism on this site.

Comment: @sphennings I don't know why you're taking this so personally! I just wanted to voice my disagreement with an opinion posted by Ray. I agree 100% with the close vote decision and the reason behind it. I never said anything at all about a close vote, in fact, until you brought it into the conversation

Comment: I would recomment this problem be moved, if you still want to know the answer.

Comment: Although some of the question appears to be answerable (by google), from the point of view of constructing a military and extending it to space flight, this would seem to be mainly opinion-based (why should it be split navy/air force/army?)

Answer (score 3):

When you build a **fictional** world, that is your decision. But it makes some sense to keep your fictional world *recognizable*.

- Military forces have long been divided into officers and enlisted men. That used to be a **class** distinction, with nobility and other upper classes giving orders and peasants and other lower classes taking orders. Read about [mustangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustang_(military_officer)) and [gentleman rankers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentleman_ranker).
- These days it is more an education issue than a class issue (even if class affects education). Think of officer training as the equivalent of an university degree -- even an entry-level officer outranks a long-service private.

Consider the use and history of the title *captain*. The rank/title of captain has evolved over the years, from "boss of a band or a ship" to more specialized uses.

- Captain is a military rank in the army and the navy. But these days the captain of a navy ship does not always have the rank of captain. The captain of a frigate may be a commander, a smaller ship might be commanded by a lieutenant commander or commander.
- You also have captains on civilian ships.
- Then there are captains of sports teams, police departments, and for flowery writers there are even *captains of industry*.

The deputy of the captain is the lieutenant.

- It used to be that a captain in charge of an army company had a lieutenant, and a captain in charge of a navy ship had several.
- On a ship, there was a first lieutenant, second lieutenant, and so on. As ships got bigger and types started to differ, the navy introduced the Commander and Lieutenant Commander between Captain and Lieutenant. Army companies stayed roughly the same size, so this didn't happen.
- But the army has colonels in charge of regiments, with lieutenant colonels as deputy, and generals in charge of armies, with lieutenant generals as deputy.

So, find a word that means "boss" and a word that means "deputy boss", and build your fictional officer ranks around it.

Comment: I also love the story behind the rank of rear admiral. The "real" admiral had to lead a bunch of ships in the ship at very front, so all others can copy its movements. Should he be killed or the ship badly damaged, others would need a backup.So, place a helper admiral, inferior to the "real" one on the last ship as backup. That's a rear admiral.